# Why doesn't my PhD&Postdoc supervisor want me to be successful?

Tags: phd, advisor, ethics, postdocs, university

I'm currently a postdoc working with the professor with whom I did my PhD work, and it counts up to 7 years for the time working with this professor.

Basically, the situation is that I'm the only one who can generate new ideas and publish on 1st-tier journals each year in the group, while the rest peers (postdoc&PhD students) can only publish on 2nd,3rd-tier journals. My supervisor himself has no capability to supervise me or generate new ideas.

With my efforts over the past few years, my publication record is very solid. The problem here is that every time I talk to other professors in other universities during conferences or visiting, my supervisor seems very unhappy and wants to know what I have discussed with other professors in our field. My feeling is that my supervisor does not want other people to see how successful I am.

This bothers me a lot because normally supervisors all want their PhD/postdocs to be successful. I don't really understand why this happens. My guess is my supervisor does not want me to leave his group.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is a good fit for this site because we cannot read your supervisor's mind. But then, you potentially already answered your own question. There is a certain percentage of actors in academia who have a rather ego-driven and exploitative mindset.

Comment: Well, if you are the workhorse of his group, of course he is not happy that you plan to leave. However, the question is whether he sabotages you or is just unhappy.

Answer (score 3):

Surely it is time to move on. Why it happens is too hard to say. Perhaps he depends on you too much. Perhaps it is jealousy.

If he could arrange a permanent position for you and give you a path to take over more explicit authority in the group you could stay, but, otherwise, your prospects are better elsewhere.

You should be applying to some permanent positions, I think. Or at least working actively toward the next phase of your career. I hope he will help you with good letters and it might be difficult for him to explain any other behavior.

But, at least, keep talking to those others and exploring options with them.

---

If the work you are doing is "sensitive" in any way then he might have a reason to know what information is getting out that isn't being published soon. That isn't quite as bad as the other options.